# How to prove that you can choose an element from a set in ZF?

Tags: logic, set-theory

Let's say we're in ZF. How would we prove the following theorem?

> Let $S$ be a set such that $S \neq \emptyset$. There exists some
>   function $f$ such that $f(S) \in S$.

It seems easy if you can start with

> Let $a \in S$, define $f = \{S\} \times \{a\}$.

But I'm not sure how ZF allows you to do that.

Comment: So each nonempty $S$ is allowed a different $f$, which needn't work for other sets, right?

Comment: It looks fine to me.  ZF certainly proves that whenever $x$ is a set then $\{x\}$ is also a set, and it also proves that Cartesian products exist.

Comment: Also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1839913/axiom-of-choice-where-does-my-argument-for-proving-the-axiom-of-choice-fail-he

Comment: This really boils down to the *underlying logic* (classical first-order logic) rather than ZF itself, specifically *existential instantiation*. Our ability to "for free" pick an object satisfying a given property is given to us even before we write down the ZF axioms.

Comment: Just a minor comment about interpretation, though I am sure that interpretation you've already given it is intended: Since $S$ is a set, $f(S)$ could also mean the set $\{f(s)\mid s \in S\}$. In that case, such an $f$ would only be possible if there is a set $A \in S$ whose cardinality is $\le$ the cardinality of $S$.